# Find the number

Tags: cipher

Ocz vinrzm dn ji ocdn kvbz

Find the numbers

Comment: You say "find the number" in the question but in your comments you say there are multiple answers.  You should specify this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the answer is

> 5

Because

> If we use Rot5 on the ciphered text it becomes "The answer is on this page"

Comment: There is another possible answer. find both possibilities

Comment: Of which you have already found one

Comment: Is S.M.'s the other possibility?

Comment: No! its just logical and simple

Comment: @Quark-epoch I think the other intended answer is 21 as, when you encoded the string you will have chosen ROT21. You only select ROT5 when you want to unencrypt the text.

Comment: yes you are right

Comment: You are right. but  just got a litlte sad looking at the response I received so i chose the closest answer as correct@GordonK

Answer (score 3):

> In rot5 this translates to "The answer is on this page" so my guess would be it's 76095, the only non-changeable number on the page (in the url)?

Edit: @hexomino's answer might make more sense, yeah.

If mine isn't correct, then taking hexomino's answer it would be:

> 5 and 13, since the url is still rot13.com and it's being translated through rot5.

Comment: There is another possible answer. Find both possibilities

Comment: Is it mine and @hexomino's?

Comment: Well tried but it is a LITTLE different

Comment: In that case there are countless possibilities, if it's on the rot13 page, it could be anywhere from 1-25, besides the numbers that are in the source code, etc. If it's on this page there are many numbers as well, like the url, the date, your reputation, etc. If you could be a bit more clear on what you're looking for...

Comment: "this page " refers to the rot13 page

Comment: It is at that moment when you get the answer so if you got it in rot 5 then there was ROT5 in the drop-down menu and thus there is another possiblity

Comment: That's what I said, in that case there are 25 other possibilities.

Comment: but the second possiblity is when you get a sensible answer

Comment: I think I'd rather close the question

Comment: 5 and 13 made sense to me, anything else seems kinda random, like saying 5 and 4 or 5 and 6 or something like that.

Comment: Ok, I will mark @hexomino's as correct